# How to await connections to socket and convert them into a FusedStream in Rust

Tags: asynchronous, rust, stream, unix-socket, rust-tokio

I have a `loop {}` around a `futures::select!`. I'd like to

1. await new connections on a Unix socket.
2. await a new message on one of the Unix streams created in 1. (preferably with some kind of uuid(sent by the connecting client in 1. directly after connecting) attached to it)

I still haven't understood the concept of a Stream correctly, especially futures-rs's "FusedFuture". I tried to create the streams I need using [tokio's async-stream](https://github.com/tokio-rs/async-stream), but that didn't work as it does not implement futures-rs's FusedFuture (which I require, as I check other streams in the same select! that benefit/require FusedFutures is_terminated() method)

I think something like [tokio_stream::StreamMap](https://docs.rs/tokio-stream/0.1.2/tokio_stream/struct.StreamMap.html) is interesting (the key as uuid and the value as a Stream that contains a tupel with the message received on the socket and reference to the UnixStream in order to write back.

I'm really sorry that I cannot provide any examples or something similar to make the issue less unclear. I've tried a lot but I was unable to come any closer to my goal. I hope the way a wrote this is somewhat understandable

Whether to use a `std::os::unix::net::UnixListener` or `tokio::net::UnixListener` is up in the air. I've tried both but was unable to achieve anything with either of them.